# Link between AQC and QAOA

Tags: qaoa, adiabatic-model, trotterization

I try to understand precisely the link between AQC and QAOA, through the Trotter-Suzuki formula.
A similar question is [Derivation of QAOA from AQC](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/30119/derivation-of-qaoa-from-aqc), but I was asked by moderators to post my question independently. So here it is.

In quantum adiabatic computing, the Hamiltonian is as follows :
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\mathcal{H} (t)= s(t)\mathcal{H}_{c}+ (1-s(t))\mathcal{H}_{m}
\end{equation}
with $s(0)=0$ and $s(T)=1$. The duration time $T$ is supposed to guarantee that the final state $|\psi\rangle(T)$ is $\varepsilon > 0$ close to the ground state of $\mathcal{H}_{c}$, the smaller $\varepsilon$, the greater $T$.

The Schrödinger equation gives :
\begin{equation}
U(t)= e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_{0}^{T}\mathcal{H}(u)\,du}= e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}\biggl(\mathcal{H}_{c}\int_{0}^{T}s(u)\,du+\mathcal{H}_{m}\int_{0}^{T}[1-s(u)]\,du\biggr)}
= e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}\biggl(\mathcal{H}_{c}S(T)+\mathcal{H}_{m}[T-S(T)]\biggr)}
\end{equation}

Applying the Trotter-Suzuki formula would give :
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
    U(T)\approx \biggl[e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}\mathcal{H}_{m} \frac{T-S(T)}{n}}e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}\mathcal{H}_{c}\frac{S(T)}{n}}\biggr]^{n}
\end{equation}

for $n\gg 1$ sufficiently high.

This formula is great as it lets one approach $U(T)$ by successively applying Hamiltonian $\mathcal{H}_c$ or $\mathcal{H}_m$ (the mixer) with some coefficients.

On the other hand, the idea usually developed to draw a link between AQC and QAOA is :
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
U(T)= U(t_n, t_{n-1})U(t_{n-1}, t_{n-2})\dots U(t_{2}, t_{1})U(t_{1}, t_{0})
\end{equation}
with $t_0 = 0$ and $t_n = T$.

This formula derives from the exact formula :
\begin{equation}
U(t)= e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_{0}^{T}\mathcal{H}(u)\,du}= 
e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}\biggl[\int_{0}^{t_1}\mathcal{H}(u)\,du+\dots+\int_{t_{n-1}}^{t_n}\mathcal{H}(u)\,du\biggr]}
=e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_{0}^{t_1}\mathcal{H}(u)\,du}\dots
e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_{t_{n-1}}^{t_n}\mathcal{H}(u)\,du}
\end{equation}

For each time interval :
\begin{equation}
U(t_{i+1},t_{i}) = e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_{t_{i}}^{t_{i+1}}\mathcal{H}(u)\,du}= e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}(\mathcal{H}_{c}\gamma_{i}+\mathcal{H}_{m}\beta_{i})}
\end{equation}

Given that :
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\gamma_{i}&= \int_{t_{i}}^{t_{i+1}}s(u)\,du\simeq s(t_{i})\,dt_{i}\simeq s(t_{i}) \frac{T}{n}\\
\beta_{i}&= \int_{t_{i}}^{t_{i+1}}[1-s(u)]\,du\simeq [1 -s(t_{i})]\,dt_{i}\simeq [1 -s(t_{i})]\frac{T}{n}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

The time segment can be approached again by Trotter Suzuki formula :
\begin{equation}
U(t_{i+1},t_{i}) = e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_{t_{i}}^{t_{i+1}}\mathcal{H}(u)\,du}= e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}(\mathcal{H}_{c}\gamma_{i}+\mathcal{H}_{m}\beta_{i})}
\simeq e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}\mathcal{H}_{c}\gamma_{i}}
e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}\mathcal{H}_{m}\beta_{i}}
\end{equation}
where we used Eq. (2) but with $n=1$ (not the same "n" as in $t_n$) as $\gamma_i$ and $\beta_i$ are already "small" enough.

One could also have used a second order approximation :

\begin{equation}
U(t_{i+1},t_{i}) \simeq e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}\mathcal{H}_{c}\frac{\gamma_{i}}{2}}
e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}\mathcal{H}_{m}\beta_{i}}
e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}\mathcal{H}_{c}\frac{\gamma_{i}}{2}}
\end{equation}

Then, this draws a direct link between Eq. 1 (AQC) and Eq. 2 (QAOA) :
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    |\psi\rangle (T)&= U_{m}(\beta_{p}) U_{c}(\gamma_{p})U_{m}(\beta_{p-1}) U_{c}(\gamma_{p-1})\dots U_{m}(\beta_{1}) U_{c}(\gamma_{1})|\psi (0)\rangle\\
    &=  e^{-i\beta_{p}H_{m}} e^{-i\gamma_{p}H_{c}}e^{-i\beta_{p-1}H_{m}} e^{-i\gamma_{p-1}H_{c}}\dots e^{-i\beta_{1}H_{m}} e^{-i\gamma_{1}H_{c}}|\psi (0)\rangle
  \end{split}
\end{equation}

where $|\psi (0)\rangle$ is the ground state of $\mathcal{H}_m$.

Is my understanding correct ?